# Changing the font-size of future elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am building a simple chat bot.On each new message received from the server, a new HTML element is created and pushed to the browser. So, for example, message 1 will be:

```
<div class="message-computer"><p>Hi, how are you?</p></div>
```

Then you (the user) types/sends a message, which shows up as:

```
<div class="message-user"><p>I am good, thanks!</p></div>
```

and so on and so forth. I created a slider to change the size of the text being sent to/from the chat bot. It now works, but it only edits EXISTING HTML elements. New messages sent to/from the server are still in the original size.

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.message-computer p').css('font-size', v + 'em')
  $('.message-user p').css('font-size', v + 'em')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" value="1" min="1" max="1.6" step=".1" id="slider" ondrag="changeSize()" />
```

How can I make the change in font size apply to all new elements sent to the browser?

Thanks

Comment: Use event delegation: `$(document).on("change", "input", function() { ... })`

Comment: Apply it to a parent element that is already in the dom so it cascades?  But why are you doing this with js?

Comment: You would need to run the code when you add the new elements.

Comment: @Pointy it is not what OP is after, OP wants the font size to apply to the new elements, not dynamic inputs.

Comment: You would be better off setting a font size on the document and have all of the elements in the CSS be based off that with rem.

Comment: @epascarello well I suppose; it's hard to tell because `"input"` is a pretty generic selector. It's possible to use `.html()` to rewrite a `<style>` block, maybe that's what he wants.

Comment: After pushing Html on message received, try `$('input').trigger('change')`

Comment: You can have the slider edit a css object that gets applied to all chat messages inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand well your problem, your code snippet doesn't contain any text.

But when using jQuery to update style, CSS statment is added individualy into each element style attribute (look at your browser inspector).
So newly added elements wont have their style attribute modified until you rechange the input value, and so will inherit from global CSS rules.

I suggest to apply the font style to the parents **.message-computer** & **.message-user**.
If you can't, wrap **p** elements into a dedicated div and apply the style to the div.

If you really need to apply it individually to each element, run `$('input').trigger('change');` just after inserting new elements into the DOM.

Comment: I also think, that best way use css classes, then when sending message add extra classes to `P`, you can do colors, sizes and eve animations. Don't shit in to your code by adding inline styles.

Comment: I totally agree, it's always better to keep styles in their right place: stylesheets. This is just a way to acheive what Simon actually asked for ^^

Comment: Ended up doing this. It was actually the most difficult solution because of my dodgy code before this, but it ended up being the correct one. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is add a class to a parent tag of your HTML, and to then have a CSS rule which applies to all of the like-elements on the page.

Then, no matter how many `.message` element you add to your `.parent` element, a CSS rule applies to them equally.

For instance, something like this would work.  You could make this approach more efficient, but this illustrates the idea.

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
var v = $(this).val();
    $('.parent').removeClass('font-1');
    $('.parent').removeClass('font-2');
    $('.parent').removeClass('font-3');
    $('.parent').removeClass('font-4');
    $('.parent').removeClass('font-5');
    $('.parent').addClass('font-' + v);
});
```

```css
.parent.font-1 .message {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.parent.font-2 .message {
    font-size: 2em;
}
.parent.font-3 .message {
    font-size: 3em;
}
.parent.font-4 .message {
    font-size: 4em;
}
.parent.font-5 .message {
    font-size: 5em;
}
.message-computer {
    color: red;
}
.message-user {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" value="1" min="1" max="5" step="1" id="slider" ondrag="changeSize()" />

<div class="parent font-1">    
    <div class="message-computer message"><p>I AM ROBOT</p></div>    
    <div class="message-user message"><p>Only human.</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only modifying existing node.
If you want that new node take those rules simply build a javascript function that add or update dynamically a css node

```
function changeSize(v)
{
     var css     = [

       ".message-computer p, .message-user p {font-size: "+v+"em;}"

    ].join("");

    var head    = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var style   = null;

    if(!document.getElementById("customTextSize"))
    {
        style = document.createElement('style');
        style.id = "customTextSize";
        style.type  = 'text/css';
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        head.appendChild(style);
    }
    else
    {
        style = document.getElementById("customTextSize");
        style.removeChild(style.firstChild);
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

    }

}
```

On your on change simply call the function :

```
    changeSize(v)
```